# Loop through list programatically

Tags: r, string, loops, arraylist

I have a list in R that I want to loop through all the elements.

This is the structure of the object:

```
> str(AAPL.OPT[c])
List of 1
 $ jun.12.2020:List of 2
  ..$ calls:'data.frame':   52 obs. of  7 variables:
  .. ..$ Strike: num [1:52] 180 185 200 210 240 ...
  .. ..$ Last  : num [1:52] 123 118 131 120 85 ...
  .. ..$ Chg   : num [1:52] 0 0 7.61 9.48 0 ...
  .. ..$ Bid   : num [1:52] 149 144 129 119 89 ...
  .. ..$ Ask   : num [1:52] 153.3 148.5 133.5 123.7 93.5 ...
  .. ..$ Vol   : int [1:52] NA 15 16 2 1 1 3 36 1 2 ...
  .. ..$ OI    : int [1:52] 0 15 25 4 50 3 4 36 6 10 ...
  ..$ puts :'data.frame':   56 obs. of  7 variables:
  .. ..$ Strike: num [1:56] 150 165 170 180 185 190 195 200 205 210 ...
  .. ..$ Last  : num [1:56] 0.05 0.02 0.14 0.05 0.03 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.01 0.01 ...
  .. ..$ Chg   : num [1:56] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ Bid   : num [1:56] NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..$ Ask   : num [1:56] 2.13 0.11 0.11 1.8 1.87 0.01 1.88 0.5 1.88 2.13 ...
  .. ..$ Vol   : int [1:56] NA 1 1 2 1 16 1 17 1 21 ...
  .. ..$ OI    : int [1:56] 1 10 7 9 76 201 113 314 92 264 ...
```

I cannot access the next level of the object programatically (by indexing the value)

I want to do something like this:

```
AAPL.OPT[c][1]
```

instead of this

```
AAPL.OPT[c]$jun.12.2020
```

Sample data of AAPL.OPT[c]

```
$`jun.12.2020`$`calls`
                    Strike   Last        Chg    Bid    Ask   Vol   OI
AAPL200612C00180000  180.0 123.29 0.00000000 149.00 153.35    NA    0
AAPL200612C00185000  185.0 117.60 0.00000000 144.00 148.50    15   15
AAPL200612C00200000  200.0 131.15 7.60999300 129.00 133.50    16   25
AAPL200612C00210000  210.0 119.95 9.47999600 119.30 123.65     2    4
....
```

Comment: I think `AAPL.OPT[[c]][[1]]` should give you `AAPL.OPT[c]$jun.12.2020`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AAPL.OPT[c]` gives a list of length 1 which has two other lists in them. If we use `[[c]]` it gives a list of length 2 andtTo access each dataframe you can subset them further using `[[` so `AAPL.OPT[[c]][[1]]` and `AAPL.OPT[[c]][[2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
 AAPL.OPT[[c]]$jun.12.2020
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.